# How can a type alias with using specify a template template argument dependent on a template argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, using, template-templates

Minimal example:

```
template<template<class ...> class>
struct templ {};

template<class T>
using special = templ<T::type>;

int main() {}
```

clang++:

```
test.cpp:5:23: error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
using special = templ<T::type>;
```

Indeed, I mean to say that `T::type` is a class template, e.g.

```
struct detail1 {
    template <class T>
    using type = std::vector<T>;
};

struct detail2 {
    template <class T>
    struct type {};
};
```

But how can one say this? g++ suggests to use `typename T::type`, but this seams wrong to me, and indeed, this does not solve the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify that `type` is a template:

```
template<class T>
using special = templ< T::template type>;
```

This is needed because `T::type` is dependent on the template parameter `T`.

See also [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Ah, I had seen things like `::template<>`, but that was new to me. Thanks!